# Directly import a csv gzip'ed file into SQLite 3

Tags: import, sqlite, csv

I'd like to import a 15GB file comma delimited gzip compressed file into Sqlite 3 without having to use temporary files.

I'd like to run a command like:

```
zcat input/surgical_code.csv.gz | tail -n +2 | sqlite3 db.sqlite ".import /dev/stdin surgical_code"
```

This decompresses the file, skips the header and tries to import.

The problem is that I am not able to specify `.mode cvs` and `.separator ","` on the same quoted command to SQlite3.

Any ideas?

Using `$(echo -e 'line1\nline2')` didn't work for me:

```
gzcat input/surgical_code.csv.gz | tail -n +2 | sqlite3 db.sqlite $(echo -e '.mode csv \n .separator \",\"\n.import /dev/stdin')
```

> `Error: mode should be one of: ascii column csv html insert line list tabs tcl`

Comment: Oh well. `echo ... | sqlite3 ...` would work, but then you'd need to get the import file from a fifo.

Answer (score 9):

I found that sqlite3 custom init script can have meta-command as well as SQL statement:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

commandfile=$(mktemp)

# create temporary init script
cat <<EOF > $commandfile
.mode csv tablename
.import /dev/stdin tablename
EOF

# import
bzip2 -d -c huge_compressed.csv.bz2 | sqlite3 --init $commandfile dbname.db
```

Comment: It might be better to create table explicitly (add `CREATE TABLE … ;` statement at the beginning of init script, and then also skip first line of csv file with `tail -n +2`), otherwise sqlite3 will make all columns of type TEXT which might be not the best result, and also lack of PRIMARY KEY makes the file larger too. Second improvement is `rm $commandfile` at the end of the script, because otherwise it might be never deleted on some systems.

Answer (score 8):

If you run `man sqlite3`, you can find command line parameters `-csv` and `-separator`.  So you can do something like this:

```
cat mycsvfile.csv | sqlite3 -csv -separator ';' mydb.db '.import /dev/stdin mycsvtable'
```

SQLite will automatically create the table if it does not exist, using the first line as the column names.  I tested this and it worked like a charm.  This is one of the fastest way to insert data into a SQLite database, comparable to prepared insert statements with pragma journal_mode=off.

If your CSV file has more than 999 columns, then you need to recompile SQLite and change SQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER from 999 to a higher number. This is because internally, SQLite uses a prepared statement bound by that limit.

Comment: couldn't get -separator arg to work on MacOSX, so used
gzcat my_table.tsv.gz | tr '\t' ',' | sqlite3 -csv my_table.db '.import /dev/stdin my_table'